# "one of our more" vs "one of our most"

Tags: phrase-choice

A colleague of mine wrote something along the lines of:

> One of our more popular employees

It seems wrong to me, shouldn't we say:

> One of our most popular employees

I think we should use **most** and not **more**, as these *employees* are not compared to something else (more popular, *than who*?)

Comment: Believe it or not, in your language is the same situation.

Comment: You're right, I had approximately the same thought the other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of our most popular employees

*Most* is superlative, meaning if something is described by *most* there is nothing "more" than it.  So here you are saying this person is in the group of employees that are at the highest level of popularity compared to anyone else.

> One of our more popular employees

Here you are just saying this employee is more popular than others, but not really providing a lot of details as to how many employees are more or less popular than him/her.

Comment: Indeed. Of course note that both terms are vague ways to praise someone without saying anything definite enough to need substantiating. :)

Comment: So the use of "One of" means that we can say both version?

Comment: Both are grammatical but they have different meanings.  But both can be used to praise someone like @LukeSawczak says.  The *most* is stronger praise than *more*.